# Json not formatted correctly using the marker [listing] inside a table

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, spring-restdocs

I'm trying to put some formatted json inside a table with Spring rest docs and asciidoctor. However the marker [listing] seems not to work inside a table. Here's an example where the first json inside the table is not formatted, whereas the same one outside the table is correctly formatted with [listing]:

```
[cols="1,2",options="header"]
|===
|Parameter|Test
{{#requestParts}}
|{{#tableCellContent}}Some {{/tableCellContent}}
|{{#tableCellContent}}

[listing]
----
{
   "name": "Richard",
   "age": 20
}
----

{{/tableCellContent}}
{{/requestParts}}
|===

[listing]
----
{
   "name": "Richard",
   "age": 20
}
----
```

How can I solve this and have my json formatted inside the table as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cols` attribute and `a` to indicate that the column should be render using [the Asciidoc style](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#cols-style). Alternatively, you can prefix the `|` that denotes the start of the cell with an `a`. This is described in the [cell formatting section](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#cell) of the Asciidoctor user manual.